# TSQL 2008 Running total with previous months & years

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to get the Running total from the values from the previous months. And if the month is january I would like to get the total from the previous year and so forth.

I hope someone can help.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT COUNT(LZP.pv_zaaknummer) AS [Aantal LZP]
, YEAR(LZP.lzp_actief_vanaf) AS Jaar
, MONTH(LZP.lzp_actief_vanaf) AS Maand
FROM dm.crm_LZP_Vn_zaaktype_leefzorgplan_registrerenExtensionBase_hist AS LZP
WHERE LZP.LZP_actief_tot_LDTS > GETDATE()
GROUP BY YEAR(LZP.lzp_actief_vanaf)
, MONTH(LZP.lzp_actief_vanaf)

)
SELECT a.Jaar
, a.Maand
, a.[Aantal LZP]
,   (
    SELECT SUM(b.[Aantal LZP])
    FROM CTE AS b
    WHERE b.Jaar <= a.Jaar
    ) AS [Running Total 1]
,   (
    SELECT SUM(b.[Aantal LZP])
    FROM CTE AS b
    WHERE b.Jaar <= a.Jaar
    AND b.Maand <= a.Maand
    ) AS [Running Total 2]
FROM   CTE AS a
ORDER BY a.Jaar, a.Maand;
```

Results as of now, I'm getting the Totals per year and then the running totals per year:

```
Jaar    Maand   Aantal LZP  Running Total 1 Running Total 2
2014    4       11                661         11
2014    5       52                661         63
2014    6       70                661         133
2014    7       76                661         209
2014    8       39                661         248
2014    9       86                661         334
2014    10      112               661         446
2014    11      120               661         566
2014    12      95                661         661
2015    1       57                3327        57
2015    2       109               3327        166
2015    3       196               3327        362
2015    4       200               3327        573
2015    5       169               3327        794
2015    6       233               3327        1097
2015    7       276               3327        1449
2015    8       224               3327        1712
2015    9       203               3327        2001
2015    10      291               3327        2404
2015    11      296               3327        2820
2015    12      412               3327        3327
2016    1       311               6062        368
2016    2       341               6062        818
2016    3       476               6062        1490
2016    4       440               6062        2141
2016    5       418               6062        2780
2016    6       500               6062        3583
2016    7       249               6062        4184
```

I would like it to be:

```
Running Total 3
11
63
133
209
248
334
446
566
661
718
827
1023
1223
1392
1625
1901
2125
2328
2619
2915
3327
3638
3979
4455
4895
5313
5813
6062
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it without subquery try

```
....................)

    SELECT a.Jaar
    , a.Maand
    , a.[Aantal LZP],SUM([Aantal LZP]) over (order by jaar) [Running Total 1]
    ,   SUM([Aantal LZP]) over (partition by jaar order by maand) [Running Total 2],
     SUM([Aantal LZP]) over ( order by jaar,maand) [Running Total 3]

    FROM   CTE AS a
    ORDER BY a.Jaar, a.Maand;
```

old version

```
SELECT a.Jaar
, a.Maand
, a.[Aantal LZP],(SELECT SUM(b.[Aantal LZP])
    FROM CTE  AS b
    WHERE b.Jaar <= a.Jaar
    ) [Running Total 1],
    (SELECT SUM(b.[Aantal LZP])
    FROM CTE  AS b
    WHERE b.Jaar <= a.Jaar and Maand<=a.Maand
    ) [Running Total 2]
,   (SELECT SUM(b.[Aantal LZP])
    FROM CTE  AS b
    WHERE dateadd(year,jaar-1900,dateadd(month,maand-1,0)) <= dateadd(year,a.jaar-1900,dateadd(month,a.maand-1,0))
    ) [Running Total 3]

FROM   CTE  AS a
ORDER BY a.Jaar, a.Maand;
```

Comment: Thanks Nazark but the OVER(PARTITION BY) clause applies to 2008 but the OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY) applies only to 2012 through 2016 only. I get an error wrong syntac near order

Comment: i have added your [Running Total 3] by the way you done for other columns please see, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution but now I must find to integrate it so it responds to my reportparameters Jaar and Maand

```
DECLARE @SalesTbl TABLE (Jaar int, Maand int, Aantal int, RunningTotal int)
DECLARE @Jaar int,
        @Maand int,
        @Aantal int,
        @RunningTotal int
SET @RunningTotal = 0
DECLARE rt_cursor CURSOR
FOR

WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT COUNT(LZP.pv_zaaknummer) AS [Aantal LZP]
, YEAR(LZP.lzp_actief_vanaf) AS Jaar
, MONTH(LZP.lzp_actief_vanaf) AS Maand
FROM dm.crm_LZP_Vn_zaaktype_leefzorgplan_registrerenExtensionBase_hist AS LZP
WHERE LZP.LZP_actief_tot_LDTS > GETDATE()
GROUP BY LZP.lzp_actief_vanaf
)


SELECT A.Jaar, A.Maand, SUM(A.[Aantal LZP])
FROM CTE AS A
GROUP BY Jaar, Maand
ORDER BY A.Jaar, A.Maand
OPEN rt_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Jaar, @Maand, @Aantal
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
 SET @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + @Aantal
 INSERT @SalesTbl VALUES (@Jaar, @Maand,@Aantal,@RunningTotal)
 FETCH NEXT FROM rt_cursor INTO @Jaar, @Maand, @Aantal
 END

CLOSE rt_cursor

DEALLOCATE rt_cursor

SELECT * FROM @SalesTbl
```